# How to find applications installed today?

Tags: apt, dpkg, software-sources

Is there any command to list which applications have been installed today via `apt-get` or `dpkg`? Is there any other way to find this information?

Answer (score 5):

Look in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. That's where the record is kept.

Answer (score 3):

To see packages installed with dpkg or a package manage different to apt we may scan `/var/log/dpkg.log`. To reveal the history may use a function posted earlier:

- [How to see packages installed on a given date using aptitude](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73180/how-to-see-packages-installed-on-a-given-date-using-aptitude)

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

to get installed packages.

---

If you're looking for something specific you can use grep to list, for example, PHP packages like this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php'
```

To get paths of a specific packages, lets say php5, run this

```
dpkg -L php5
```

You can read more in this guide right here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/ or in the manual by running.

```
man dpkg
```

Comment: Yes, but this shows all applications installed. I need to display recently installed apps e.g. today or since 2 days.

Comment: Please update your question, with that information.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get a little more perverse (and precise) than this, if you need the output for scripting, for example, but if you're just looking for a day's activity:

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d" | xargs -i% sed -n "/%/,/%/p" /var/log/apt/history.log
Start-Date: 2013-06-18  14:24:33
Commandline: apt-get install workrave
Install: workrave:amd64 (1.10-0ubuntu2), workrave-data:amd64 (1.10-0ubuntu2, automatic), libgdome2-0:amd64 (0.8.1+debian-4.1build1, automatic)
End-Date: 2013-06-18  14:24:40
Start-Date: 2013-06-18  16:58:40
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Install: linux-image-3.8.0-26-generic:amd64 (3.8.0-26.38, automatic), linux-headers-3.8.0-26:amd64 (3.8.0-26.38, automatic), linux-tools-3.8.0-26:amd64 (3.8.0-26.38, automatic), linux-headers-3.8.0-26-generic:amd64 (3.8.0-26.38, automatic), linux-image-extra-3.8.0-26-generic:amd64 (3.8.0-26.38, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-tools:amd64 (3.8.0.25.43, 3.8.0.26.44), linux-generic:amd64 (3.8.0.25.43, 3.8.0.26.44), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.8.0.25.43, 3.8.0.26.44), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.8.0.25.43, 3.8.0.26.44), linux-tools-common:amd64 (3.8.0-25.37, 3.8.0-26.38), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.8.0-25.37, 3.8.0-26.38)
End-Date: 2013-06-18  17:00:07
```