# List packages by creation / modification (not install) date to find unmaintained ones

Tags: apt, package-management

I would like to go over my packages and double-check whether I am using any that haven't been updated (by the authors) in a long time.

Related to this:

- [How do I get a list of obsolete packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98223/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-obsolete-packages) asks about packages that do no longer have a version in the package repositories.
- [How to see packages installed on a given date using aptitude](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73180/how-to-see-packages-installed-on-a-given-date-using-aptitude) and many others talk about installation dates

I am interested in the date the package was changed on the server, not on my computer.
I don't have high hopes since I couldn't find such a date in any of the `apt-cache` commands I have tried so far and `apt-get` doesn't seem to be better suited either. Is this possible somehow?

Afterthought: The changelogs in Synaptic contain the dates I want. Would I have to download all of them and somehow process those in a script?

Answer (score 0):

If you could generate a list from the apt sources download location then the last modified dates are on the server. This is the only place I can find that has anything date related.

for e.g http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/